# Pass parameter from list in file

Tags: bash, loops, shell

i'm struggling with this topic: I've a file with a list of IDs, something like this:

```
34
23
478
12579
342356
```

On the other side, i've a command that i want to run, to show me the details for each object of the list (no much to say on this, is a specific command coming actually from a API). It looks like this, where "id" rappresents a single integer, which must exist in the previous list.

```
command-to-get-details str id
```

My idea was to loop in the first file with `read`, store the IDs in a variable through `readarray`and pass them to the second command in a while loop. The problem with this solution is that i can't use `readarray` in this machine.

Is there any other solution to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you need to store them in an array? Just loop through the file with `read` and execute the command in that loop.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: And if you do need them in an array, you can append to the array in the `read` loop. `while read -r id; do array+=($id); done < filename`

Comment: @Barmar oki yes if not required i can avoid to store them in an array, but how you would do that? Can you please provice a code snippet? Thank you :)

Comment: _"The problem with this solution is that i can't use `readarray` in this machine"_ If you're executing bash then you should be able to use `mapfile`; `readarray` is actually a synonym of `mapfile`, introduced in bash 4.0

Comment: Asides from the suggestions by _Barmar_ and _Fravadona_, you could also use `xargs`.

Comment: @t30_9 Did you follow the link Shawn gave? It shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r id
do
    echo "command-o-get-details str $id"
done < "ids.txt"
```

Remove the echo to use your specific command.

Comment: Works very very good, thank you very much and thank you for the reference. I know how to do this in future :)